# Manipulating SOAP request paramenters when Integrating with SOAPUI in Java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, soapui

I am trying to set up an Fitnesse fixture for testing SOAP services. I am trying to use the SoapUI API to build requests from the WSDL, and probably send and disseminate the responses. I am trying to integrate with the SoapUI API as described here: [Integrating with SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/Developers-Corner/integrating-with-soapui.html).

I can read in my .wsdl file fine and create a template for the SOAP request based on the operation I am wanted to call. However, for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to manipulate the operation's parameter fields in the request.

Example Request for the `getName` operation:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:Foo">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:getName soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <in xsi:type="urn:GetNamedRequest">
            <name xsi:type="xsd:string">?</name>
         </in>
      </urn:updateRecord>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

From this example, I want to be able to change the `<name/>` item.

Ideally, I want to be able to use the SoapUI API to change it, if it offers that feature. But the documentation is poorly commented and infuriating. I am not beyond taking the request it generates and manipulating it to my ends, but would rather not go to that measure as the API surely has some way to manipulate the inner html of `<name/>`.

Can anyone help or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I actually just dealt with this and sadly, there really isn't that many decent ways to handle it. It really depends on how you are getting the XML etc etc. I will presume you have the XML in a w3c.dom formatting. If not, you can use

```
XmlUtils.selectFirstDomNode(XmlUtils.createXmlObject(xmlString),XPath);
```

to create a node.

After that, use

```
XmlUtils.setNodeValue(Node,Value);
```

And then, depending on how you set up your request, I had to bring it back to a string:

```
XmlUtils.prettyPrintXml(Node);
```

The way SoapUI handles it's request content is very difficult to work with. It's a running joke around my office honestly, but this works quite well for us for now.